# Contents of grid are in wrong column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have this XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="layers" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Button Height="20" Content="Add layer" Click="aL_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button Height="20" Content="Add static layer" Click="aSL_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, ListView is in column 1 of Grid and the StackPanel is in column 2 of Grid. But when I run this and add Image to ListView, the ListView (and Image) are showing in column 2 of Grid, after StackPanel.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: As any other common indices, column and row indices start at zero. Besides that, setting ColumnSpan only makes sense if an element should span (i.e. occupy) more than one column.

Comment: @Clemens if you'll post answer, I'll checkmark

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First column is column "0" and not "1".
There is no sense for expression `Grid.ColumnSpan="1"` because it is default value as well as `Grid.Column="0"`.

Answer (score 0):

I just done what I want this way:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="layers">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Height="20" Content="Add layer" Click="aL_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
        <Button Height="20" Content="Add static layer" Click="aSL_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment from Clemens helped me.